# How would you model the following database relationship?

Tags: sql, database-design

There are departments and managers. A department has more managers, but only one manager is the chief manager of the department. A department must have only one chief manager. During holidays, a chief manager from a department can be the temporary chief manager of another department. How would you model this ?

Please explain your choice.

Comment: Sounds like homework. You should add that tag to your question if so.

Comment: No, it is simplified real life situation I have encountered. I have more modeling ideas, and I was curious of hearing other ideas.

Comment: Can the same manager manage more than one department at a time? Also, are there any additional fields that a chief manager should have that "ordinary" managers don't?

Comment: All the managers (ordinary or chief) belong to only one department. For temporary periods (e.g. 1 week) a chief manager will be the chief of his own department, and additionally will be the temporary chief manager of other departments (when another chief manager is on holiday or sick). And for the second question, no, ordinary managers and chief managers have the same fields.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a single "ordinary" manager can manage at most one department, your data model should probably look something like this:

[image]

A CHIEF_MANAGER_ID can "point" either:

- to a manager from the same department (i.e. whose MANAGER.DEPARTMENT_ID matches the DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID of the row containing this CHIEF_MANAGER_ID), in which case it is the **"primary"** chief manager
- or to a manager from the different department, in which case it is the **"substitute"** chief manager.

In case you want to ensure a same person cannot manage multiple departments in its role as a chief manager (while still being able to manage one more department as an ordinary manager), add a UNIQUE constraint on CHIEF_MANAGER_ID.

In case you need to memorize both primary and substitute chief managers *at the same time*, use two fields instead of just CHIEF_MANAGER_ID (in which case, you'd also have to enforce department matching non-declaratively).

In the model above, the DEPARTMENT.CHIEF_MANAGER_ID is NULL-able. This is done to break the cycle of foreign keys, so data could actually be inserted into the database without deferring foreign keys. If your DBMS supports deferrable constraints, you can make this field NOT NULL and defer one of the FKs, so it is checked at the end of the transaction (after both rows have been inserted).

---

I just realized there is an additional requirement: not every manager can be substitute. Only a chief can. You could do something like this to model it:

[image]

The SUBSTITUTE_DEPARTMENT_ID points to the department we are "borrowing" the chief manager substitute from. Since we are pointing to a department, and not directly manager, we know we must be getting the **chief** manager with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have also considered this model. It is true that I want to memorize both primary and temporary manager. My question regarding this solution is: For the temporary manager I need to save the period of this temporary position, so that I know when I have to count on the primary manager or on the substitute/temporary manager. Where should I do that ? In the department table ? (it would not look nice)

Comment: @CarlBruun You could probably just add the start/end date fields to the DEPARTMENT (in the model at the bottom of my updated answer). This way, you keep both primary and substitute, and know _when_ to use which. Of course, if you need _multiple_ periods, it would require an additional table.

Comment: It seems to be the only way to add the start/end date from your point of view as well. But I consider inappropriate (or not so nice) to save these two data in the department table, but it is a solution, and covers all the requirements. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One table for departments, one table for managers, one table for chief managers.

A relational table for managers to departments, a relational table for chief managers to departments, a relational table for chief managers to other departments they are allowed to oversee (or instead, if it results in a smaller data set, the table should be relational for chief managers to departments they are NOT allowed to oversee).

Comment: The relation between Department and Chief manager would then be a one-to-one relationship. I was thinking of creating a single table manager and store the id of the chief manager in the department table. What do you think of this?

Comment: @CarlBruun This is good also. Actually, fewer tables, so it would be better. That is as long as managers and chief managers don't have to be separated for any reason.

Comment: The reason I am unsure of my model is that it allows to remove a manager even if its ID is saved as chief manager in a department, resulting in having a department with an nonexistent manager id.

Comment: Then, perhaps it would be best to go with my original design. The relational table for chief manager to department would provide the referential integrity to prevent that accident. If the department or chief manager changed, the data would still exist to show that that relationship had at one time existed, but a new relationship would have to be created to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this model

Department
(
IdDepartment,
other properties ...
)

Manager
(
Idmanager,
other properties ...
)

DepartmentManager
(
IdDepartment,
IdManager,
IsTemporary
)

In your physical model

DepartmentTable
 IdDepartment as primary key

ManagerTable
 IdManager as primary key

DepartmentManagerTable
  (IdDepartment + IdManager) as primary key
  IsTemporaryChef  as property

Comment: And how would this model stop a department having two chief managers ?  (not temporary ones)

Comment: if your department have two chefs you can have in your database in the table of link 
(iddepartment : 1, idmanager : 1, idtemporary :1)
(iddepartment : 1, idmanager : 2, idtemporary :0)

Comment: the business rule says it is not allowed to have more than one chief manager belonging to a department.

Comment: Ok, but the functional need can increase, and my model take easily these evolution.

Answer (score 0):

One table for departments (including chief manager ID)

One table for Managers (Per person)

One table for Department/Manager relationships (Department ID & Manager ID)

Example:

[image: Schema Example]

Comment: What's the reason for having the Department-manager relationship table for your model ?

Comment: This allows one manager to be connected to more than one department and also one department to have more than one manager, storing the chief manager ID in the department table ensures only one chief per department.

Comment: In a normal situation a manager belongs to only one department. The only different case is when a Chief manager becomes the temporary Chief manager of an another department. The Mgr_Dept_Link table would not be useful in this case, would be ?

Comment: When you say "A department has more managers" I assume a one to many relationship for departments > managers, if this is wrong it might need clarifying.

Comment: Yes, but your model is a many to many relationship between department and manager because of the link table, and this should not be allowed.

Comment: So one department can have many managers, but can a manager manage only a single department? If so then this needs adding to the question as you only define a limit for chief managers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12704/discussion-between-carl-bruun-and-bendataclear)

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here is to separate hierarchy of an organizational chart from employees (manager is an employee). Like the difference between the President (position) and the person who holds the office.

For simplicity, the hierarchy is here modelled with the levelled-adjacency-list; not most efficient for SQL hierarchies, but good enough for this.

Note, chief manager of a department has a position that does not report to anyone in that department. CEO of the whole organization has `ReportsTo = NULL`, for everyone else it points to the boss-position.

Each employee can fulfill any role over time.

For more efficient hierarchy models, see Celko's book or just google 'SQL hierarchies'.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your model actually allows an employee being part of more than one department, right ? If true, it does not cover my requirement

Comment: True, one employee may play several roles at the same time. You may or may not prevent that with constraints. The reality is that people are promoted and demoted up-down hierarchy on pleasure of upper-management, a person often works two positions part-time. 
That being said, there are few more things to  take pay attention to - like promoting nodes if boss-position is deleted, having all positions filled with people, preventing cyclical loops ... It may be way more flexible to implement rule-based-checks (on app level or stored-proc) then to constrain everything with plain DB constraints.